# Conditional statement destroyed frame

Tags: beamer, conditionals, themes, frame-title

I tryed to get a different headline on the title page with if else fi, but it destroyed the frame styles. Why?

Need help in beamertheme.sty

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \ifnum \insertpagenumber=1
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=2mm, dp=1mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
  \else
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=2mm, dp=1mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vspace*{1mm}%
    \hspace{1mm}\includegraphics[width=0.1\paperwidth]{fig/logo.png}%
    \vspace{1mm}%
    \newline%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=0.5mm, dp=1mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi
}
\setbeamercolor{head1}{fg=white, bg=black}
```

[image: Title page with if else fi]
[image: First frame with if else fi]

without if else fi

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=2mm, dp=1mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vspace*{1mm}%
  \hspace{1mm}\includegraphics[width=0.1\paperwidth]{fig/logo.png}%
  \vspace{1mm}%
  \newline%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=0.5mm, dp=1mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\setbeamercolor{head1}{fg=white, bg=black}
```

[image: Title page without if else fi]
[image: First frame without if else fi]

**Update:** It looks like the next pages are aligned with the first headline.

Comment: The height of the `headline` template must be constant...

Comment: @PaulGaborit You are right. I misread the question. Merci!

Comment: @PaulGaborit I added enough \vspace and it works thx, but actually i wanted the headline on the title page to be bigger with a bigger LOGO. Is there a way to separate the first page from anothers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a dirty solution (works only if the headline on the title page is bigger):

beamerthemeooo.sty

```
% Head line for frames
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{headline frames}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=3mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vspace*{1mm}%
  \hspace*{1mm}\includegraphics[height=8mm]{fig/logo.png}%
  \vspace*{1mm}%
  \newline%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=1mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
}
% Head line for title page
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{headline titlepage}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=3mm]{head1}\end{beamercolorbox}%
  \vspace*{1mm}
  \hspace*{1mm}\includegraphics[height=30mm]{fig/logo.png}
}
\setbeamercolor{head1}{fg=white, bg=black}
```

beamer.tex

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[headline frames]% for whole document
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[headline titlepage]% change to titlepage headline
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}[headline frames]% change back to frame headline
```

[image: new title page]
[image: new frame page]